# Config nginx proxy for tomcat app on Ubuntu

Tags: nginx, tomcat, java, http-headers, angular

I have that config for nginx:

```
    server {
listen 80;
server_name myDomain;
access_log /var/log/nginx/tomcat-access.log;
error_log /var/log/nginx/tomcat-error.log;

underscores_in_headers on;

if ($host = http://myDomain){
   return 302 https://$host$request_uri;
}

location / {
    #include proxy_params;
    #proxy_set_header Host $server_name;
    #proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    #proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/myApp/;
}

location /myApp/min {
    alias /var/www/httpdocs/prd.myApp.old/myapp/src/main/resources/static/min/;
}

location /assets/ {
    alias /var/www/httpdocs/prd.myApp.old/myapp/src/main/resources/static/assets/;
}

listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/app.myApp.de/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/app.myApp.de/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot}
```

MyApp deploy at tomcat9 on Ubuntu 22 with pass localhost:8080/myApp. It is Java WAR + Angular + JSP inside. My question is what header I need to use to correct connect all redirection? Because if I use "include proxy_params" I have infinity redirect error. If I use without any headers have https loop 302 on login page without any submit. If I use 3 rows proxy_set_header from code snippet I have incorrect redirect to https://myDomain/myApp////////////// and after that have redirect to 404 bcz path is corrupted instead of myDomain/login to myDomain/myApp/login.

Please explain how it works and how I can fix that.

Comment: Most often these issues happen because the root URL of the web application is not set properly in your application configuration. So, if you want your app to be accessible at `https://www.example.com/app/`, you need to set the root URL in your app configuration.